# Breeze Join Query

Tags: jquery, join, breeze, contains

Is it possible to perform a query join with breeze? I have a dataset from from different contexts (databases) and will want to perform a join on these. Performing a "contains" operation is an option but can be too slow.

How can a join be done or what are its alternatives in breeze?

Comment: A little more context would be helpful.

Comment: @JayTraband I have two context for each of my databases and I want to return data from one context based on a join with the other context.

Comment: You're doing a cross database join?

Comment: I am doing a full join. Is it possible to do any sort of join?

Comment: You can do whatever you want on the server ... that your server permits ... and expose the results through an endpoint that you can hit with a Breeze client. Breeze is happy to talk to any HTTP endpoint that responds with JSON. What you do with that JSON result on the client is up to you. You can treat it as data. You can treat it as an entity type ... if you're prepared to describe that type in metadata and detect/identity the JSON data as that type.